# Subquery with LATERAL VIEW in hive 0.13

Tags: hadoop, subquery, hive, hiveql

I am using Apache Hive 0.13 (which supports Sub-Queries) and I am trying to run a query whose sub-query uses LATERAL VIEW and explode(). I keep getting NPE :

FAILED: NullPointerException null

I have tried the sub-query separately & independently, and it works fine. I also could not find any limitations in using LATERAL VIEW for sub-queries in Hive's [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)

So I am wondering what the issue is with my query. You can see the query below:

```
select u.name, u.employment 
from users u 
where u.id IN (
SELECT distinct su.id 
FROM users su LATERAL VIEW explode(su.employment) empTable AS emp 
where su.frCount >= 10 
and su.frCount < 20 
and emp.endDate is NULL
);
```

I am using Hive with JSON data. Here is the DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id BIGINT,   
name string, 
frCount INT, 
employment array<struct<
                  organization_name : string,
                  start_date: BIGINT, 
                  end_date: BIGINT>>
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: could you provide an example of what the data in the table you are querying from looks like?

Comment: Thnx for reply. Just added DDL above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Hive left semi join.

```
select u.name, u.employment
from users u left semi join
(SELECT distinct su.id 
FROM users su LATERAL VIEW explode(su.employment) empTable AS emp 
where su.frCount >= 10 
and su.frCount < 20 
and emp.endDate is NULL) t on u.id = t.id
```